# Spring - SMTPSendFailedException Authentication Required only when the web app deploy on the GCP

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, google-cloud-platform

I have a very strange problem,
When I try to send an email when the WEBAPP runs on the computer locally everything works great.
But when I upload the WEBAPP to Google's server it throws me

```
Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError g1sm2030389ioj.45 - gsmtp\n"
```

this is the class that sends the Emails

```
@Service
public class MailService {
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

@Autowired
public MailService(JavaMailSender mailSender) {
    this.mailSender = mailSender;
}

@Async
public void sendMail(ArrayList<String> mails, String body, String title){
    SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
    mailMessage.setFrom("some mail");
    mailMessage.setSubject(title);
    mailMessage.setText(body);
    for (String to :
            mails) {
        mailMessage.setTo(to);
        mailSender.send(mailMessage);
    }

}

}
```

what could i be?! works perfecty fine on the IDE but when i deploy on the tomcat servlet its exeptioning.

i enabled less secure apps on the user settings

Answer (score 0):

GCP blocks standard email ports , you can choose a non-standard port to send email through. You can also take advantage of the mail services offered by Compute Engine partners: SendGrid, Mailgun, and Mailjet.

See here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail

Comment: I'm trying to send a standard smtp mail from a gmail I need to open ports for that!?

Comment: Do you use Gmail app, or standard Java mail api, which tries to send email from sender with Gmail address?

Comment: I'm using java mail API now I see that I can and recommend to use 3rd party mail services now in my spring app I need to put the host etc... in the propriety file instead of the gmail?

Comment: You have to implement this third party API - open account in a third party service and use its library in your app.